# Data is not added well to ListView. (C# window form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I added 3 columns.

The modified attribute values are as follows.

1. View - Details
2. Onwer - True
3. GirdLines - True
4. FullRowSelect - True

```
namespace TestWinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //listView1.BeginUpdate();
            string[] row = { "123", "456", "789" };
            ListViewItem list_view = new ListViewItem(row);
            listView1.Items.Add(list_view);
            textBox1.Text = listView1.Items.Count.ToString();
            //listView1.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

It is a code that updates the number of current rows to the `textbox1` after adding a data row every time the `add` button is clicked.

Obviously, The number of rows keeps going up.... but the data is not output to `listView1`.

Which part should I check?

Comment: Have you actually added the columns to the `ListView`? I would probably recommend not using a `ListView` anyway. In most cases where people do, they ought to be using a `DataGridView`, generally bound to a `DataTable` or some other data source via a `BindingSource`.

Comment: What does *Owner - True* mean? Did you set `OwnerDraw = true`? If so, then you have to draw the Items yourself. Are you?

Comment: Yes, you are right about ownerDraw. I'll try again using DataGridView. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should work in detail view with columns added. Here is an example

Design view

[image]

In this case a instance of the following class is used so later we can get information about a specific row.

```
public class Contact
{
    public int CustomerIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneTypeDescription { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string[] ItemArray => new[]
    {
        CompanyName,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        PhoneNumber,
        CountryName
    };
}
```

Code to do a mock add

```
private void AddRowButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var companyName = "Just added";

    Contact contact = new Contact()
    {
        CompanyName = companyName,
        FirstName = "Karen",
        LastName = "Payne",
        PhoneNumber = "123-333-4444",
        CountryName = "USA"
    };

    ownerContactListView.Items.Add(
        new ListViewItem(contact.ItemArray)
        {
            Tag = contact.CustomerIdentifier
        });

    CountLabel.Text = $@"Row count: {ownerContactListView.Items.Count}";

    var index = ownerContactListView.Items.IndexOf(
        ownerContactListView.FindItemWithText(companyName));

    ownerContactListView.Items[index].Selected = true;
    ownerContactListView.EnsureVisible(index);
    ActiveControl = ownerContactListView;
}
```

After adding the row above (note I shorten the form so what you see is a partial view)

[image]

You can see the entire the initial load, see [the following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/ListViewWindowsForms/blob/master/BasicListViewDetailViewExample/ContactForm.cs#L51:L89).

Answer (score 0):

Havent used Winforms in ages, but I remember that using a binding source was more reliable

```
var bindingSource = new BindingSource();
bindingSource.DataSource = dataTable;
grid.DataSource = bindingSource;

//Add data to dataTable and then call

bindingSource.ResetBindings(false)
```

Comment: A `BindingSource` won't help with a `ListView` control because it doesn't support data-binding. If a `DataGridView` was being used, as it probably should, then binding via a `BindingSource` would be the most appropriate option.